# @ngui/auto-complete and ng2-daterangepicker incompatibility with angular 16

Tags: angular, autocomplete, daterangepicker, angular16, angular-daterangepicker

I have updated my angular project from v11 to v16. I am using @ngui/auto-complete and ng2-daterangepicker in my project. I am getting error importing NguiAutoCompleteModule and Daterangepicker module. Error saying ***'NguiAutoCompleteModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class***. Aslo for Daterangepicker. Also saying ***This likely means that the library (@ngui/auto-complete) which declares NguiAutoCompleteModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy.*** These 2 npm packages are no longer maintained by their owner and do not have support for Angular 16.

What can I do in this situation to make these package working in my project? Please give me a solution.

I tried updating all packages as much as possible. But nothing worked. It would be really helpful if any solution can make them working with angular 16.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, its not compatible with the Ivy engine, so look for alternative packages which do the same functionality, do not try to workaround this, since angular has Ivy as the default renderer!

As a parallel measure you can report this issue on their github and see if the maintainers might consider fixing this!